# Индикатор очереди проверок

Tags: поддержка, предложение, статус-так-задумано

Почему индикатор (число) длины очереди проверок в шапке сайта отображает только число сообщений требующих утверждения после редактирования, а не суммарное кол-во ситуаций требующих внимания со стороны пользователей для улучшения сайта?

Ведь помимо секции *Предлагаемые правки* существуют и другие, такие как:

- Голоса за закрытие
- Сообщения низкого качества
- Первые сообщения
- Запоздалые ответы
- Голоса за повторное открытие

Почему бы их всех не включать в то число, что отображается сейчас только для 
*Предлагаемые правки* ? Мне кажется это ускорило бы процесс проверок. Например, сейчас [длина очереди](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review) на закрытие - 79. Это довольно много, я считаю.

> [image: 79]

Картина в целом выглядит вот так:

> [image: индикатора нет, очередь далеко не пуста]

Т.е. индикатора нет, а очередь при этом далеко не пуста.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вижу уведомление о собственных правках, ждущих в очереди](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/944/%d0%92%d0%b8%d0%b6%d1%83-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8)

Comment: @Discord у меня другая (обратная) ситуация. Лампочек нет, а вот внутри очередь очень как не пустая.

Comment: Ну грубая оценка в другую сторону ошиблась. Не вижу принципиальной разницы.

Comment: @Discord не уверен. Если оценка от случая к случаю ошибается, это одно. Я же вижу стабильно ситуацию, что лампочки нет, а голосов на закрытие, например, тьма.

Comment: Гм, не воспроизводится. У меня счётчик никуда не пропадает, там оценка суммы сверху.

Comment: @Discord добавил картинку в вопрос. У вас не так же (на основном сайте, не мета)?

Comment: У меня 83=77+1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Индикатор отображает количество сообщений в очереди для модераторов и участников, получивших привилегию «[инструменты модератора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)».

Существуют уникальные настройки для каждого сайта. [Например](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726/274323), на Stack Overflow на английском в счетчике не учитываются голоса за закрытие вопросов, а сам индикатор очереди (счетчик количества элементов) появляется лишь в случае, если общее количество элементов более десяти.

Сам индикатор хранится в кэше.

Comment: Эти уникальные настройки известны? Чем обоснована их уникальность?

Answer (score 1):

Это как-то к рейтингу привязано. Сначала считаются только предлагаемые правки, а после какого-то рубежа начинает считаться всё, что есть в очередях.

Comment: Возможно, это рубеж в 10000 баллов, после которых даётся доступ к [Инструментам модератора](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: @GlebKemarsky да. Так и есть. [Можно посмотреть как изменился индикатор у меня при переходе 10К реп.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35169001#35169001)