# Подсветка кнопки очередей не учитывает лимиты

Tags: дефект, дизайн, очередь-проверок

Открыл страницу (только что), иконка подвсечена, а везде нули.
Just opened the page and saw highlighted review icon with all zeroes inside.

[image: скриншот]

Если заглянуть на страницу со всеми очередями, то видно, что есть 10 сообщений низкого качества, но проверка этой очереди мне недоступна из-за дорстижения дневного лимита проверок. Вероятно, подсветка срабатывает из-за этой очереди.

If look at the all queues page, you can see 10 low quality posts, but that queue is not available because of the daily limit. Seems like highlighting occures because of that queue.

[image: скриншот очередей]

Answer (score 2):

Не думаю, что это можно исправить при текущем подходе к работе с очередью проверок. Как известно, ранее, пока была шапка с числом, это число отражало некоторое общее на весь сайт количество проверок. То есть оно не было привязано к конкретному участнику и его лимитам. Собственно, я сам задавал вопрос тогда по похожей ситуации: [Индикатор очереди проверок](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3219/176217)

Сейчас же ситуация изменилась лишь в том плане, что десятичное число превратилось в булево. [С некоторыми особенностями, правда.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5377/176217)

То есть, лимиты по-прежнему не учитываются. А значит, подсветка иконки будет появляться всё равно. Пока сам подсчет не получится сделать с учетом индивидуальных особенностей.

Comment: Но числа отображаются индивидуально для пользователя. И список очередей - тоже. И подсветка уже индивидуальна - она появляется, если состояние в очереди изменилось с момента последнегго посещения. Так что что-то ты какую-то устаревшую информацию мне подкидываешь.

Comment: @Qwertiy насколько я понимаю, "индивидуальность" со счетчиком срабатывает при явном открытии страницы /review или же выпадающего меню из панели навигации. А если просто ходить по другим страницам, то никакой индивидуальности счетчиков по-прежнему нет. Так как это [нагружало бы сервак](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252845/3240681) непомерно.

Comment: [Скринвидео](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/LG1R/RNvG7U85s) - я обновляю страницу, открываю страницу очередей проверки, потом открываю первую страницу снова - все значения одинаковые, но подсветка исчезла - значит, подсветкка иконки зависит от пользователя.

Comment: @Qwertiy так после посещения страницы `/review` подсветка гаснет на час минимум. Об этом написано по ссылке в ответе.

Comment: Ну так значит, она персональная?

Comment: @Qwertiy в какой-то части да, но не в части кол-ва требуемых проверок. Поэтому я и написал "С некоторыми особенностями".